# call didRegisterUserNotificationSettings from a different app delegate function

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I am adding an onboarding guide to my app and want to ask users to register for notifications on a specific slide of the guide. I want to know if there is a way to call the didRegisterUserNotificationSettings function from my onboarding function. If I can't call it directly, is there way to create a different function that does the same functionality and can be called by my onboarding function?

**edit** I just added

```
 let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

I am now getting the following error

> Uiusernotificationsettings is not convertible to uiapplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Call `registerForNotificationTypes:` when you are in that "specific slide of the guide".

But, the popup comes only once. If the user, god forbid, has disabled the notification for your app, at the most, you can give him the option to take him to the settings page where he should manually enable it. (Make sure you don't annoy him too much with it.)

Note that it is useless to call `didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:` as it is a delegate method that is called when your app is successfully registered for notifications.

**Edit**

This is how you should register

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Comment: I just made the change (see edit) to the slide but am getting an error

Comment: Don't doubt that it does, but am not sure what to do about the error